# PHP Pure functions

Tags: php, purely-functional

I am trying to identify [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) in PHP code.

A pure function is one where both these statements about the function hold:

- The function always evaluates the same result value given the same argument value(s). The function result value cannot depend on any hidden information or state that may change as program execution proceeds or between different executions of the program, nor can it depend on any external input from I/O devices.
- Evaluation of the result does not cause any semantically observable side effect or output, such as mutation of mutable objects or output to I/O devices.

(definition from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function))

Is it sufficient to say that a PHP function is pure if and only if

- all its arguments are passed by value (no `&` in the argument list)
- it does not use object members (no `$this` in the function body)
- it does not use globals (it doesn't contain `global` in the function body)
- it does not use superglobals (it doesn't contain `$_` variables)

Are these statements true ?
Am I missing any use cases ?

Comment: I think this question should be in the computer science Stackexchange.

Comment: Cannot generate any output, write anything to file, etc

Comment: If you pass an object into a function/method then it's entirely possible for that object's state to be mutated from within the function/method.  All objects are effectively passed by reference.

Comment: @MarkBaker I believe file IO is allowed provided it meets some fairly strict constraints. As for generating output, if you mean it returns something then that's fine.  If you mean it echos something then that would be impure.

Comment: @GordonM, in PHP objects are being passed by value

Comment: @UriGoren That hasn't been the case since PHP 5.0.0  http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: I have no idea why @GordonM is saying there is allowed to be file IO for certain cases, this seems to go against the underlying theme of what makes a function "pure". Perhaps they would like to elaborate? Here is a quick example of what @Mark Baker is saying about output. If the function has any echos at all, like `echo "hello";`, then it is not pure. Instead of doing that, it might return that value, like `return "hello";`

Comment: @still_dreaming_1 Like I said there are a handful of cases where it's okay.  For example if you just do a file_get_contents() or similar then that doesn't change any state outside of the function.  Other operations like file-locking, fread (or other functions that change the file pointer position), fwrite (which changes the file) etc are not pure.  As you pointed out echo is an IO function and isn't pure.

Comment: @GordonM I'm still not following you. I would think reading from a file would still make for an impure function because the behavior of your function could change based on something other than what arguments are passed in, it can also change based on the contents of the file being read. Given the same arguments to your function, the file can contain different contents.

Comment: Hey, how did this go? I need exactly the same thing, so I can remove dead function calls with no side effects

Comment: https://github.com/urigoren/PHPure

Answer (score 4):

## You are missing a lot of use-cases

- `rand()`
- database interaction
- file IO
- `static` variables
- calls to other functions with `global`
- `import`/`require` statements inside functions
- functions with internal state like `ob_get_contents()`
- mutating array pointers

There is probably a lot of stuff I'm not thinking of. PHP has a very stateful design.